# Calling my own predicate in "where" in Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I want to be able to call a function or my predicated in "where" of Ecto. I'm trying this:

```
items = where(Item, [x], Item.my_predicate?(x))

# items = where(Item, [x], Item.my_predicate?(x) == true)
```

It throws an exception:

```
`Item.my_predicate?(x)` is not a valid query expression
```

How to fix it?

Comment: This is not possible. When you have a query like this, it needs to translate to your databases query language. If you started writing arbitrary code inside of it, ecto would not be able to make that translation.

Comment: It would be easier to provide you more help if you would provide us sample of the predicate that you want to run and DB that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible however you cannot use functions [but macros](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.2.6/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1).

Example:

```
defmodule Foo do
  defmacro concat_ws(joiner, columns) do
    params_list = "?" |> List.duplicate(Enum.count(columns)) |> Enum.join(",")

    quote do
      fragment(unquote("concat_ws(?," <> params_list <>" )", joiner, unquote_splicing(columns))
    end
  end
end

items = where(Item, [x], Foo.concat_ws(" ", [x.a, x.b]) == "a b")
```

---

Example without `fragment`:

```
defmodule Foo do
  defmacro eql(a, b) do
    quote do: not (is_nil(a) or is_nil(b)) and a == b 
  end
end
```

But still macro result need to be valid query AST, so nothing fancy can land there.

Comment: why macros? How can I use my own predicate which needs no fragments?

Comment: @Bingi still you need to use macro as `where` is also macro which builds `Ecto.Query` structure with required AST. There is no way to call function on columns data as it would require Ecto to translate that function code to DB query. Everything in Ecto query need to be either precomputed and send to DB as raw data or need to be translatable to query. You do not need to use `fragment` but in general this is case when you need Ecto macros. However you are free to write any code there that you could use in query, otherwise it is not possible.

Comment: How can I use my own predicate which needs no fragments?

Comment: @Bingi in that case it is impossible for the reason I have given above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.

As one way to go, you could create a separate policy module which implements function to handle it on a record or as a part of the query:

```
defmodule CheapItemPolicy do
  alias Ecto.Query
  import Query, only: [where: 3]

  def is_cheap?(%Item{price: price}) do
    price in 100..200
  end

  def is_cheap?(%Query{} = query) do
    query 
    |> where([q], q.price >= 100)
    |> where([q], q.price <= 200)
  end
end
```

Obviously it's just one way to go. You could put all these functions into already existing module or break them into separate modules or create a database function with the same logic or handle the checking on the application level or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Lukasz's answer is what you need. Ecto queries are built at compile time, so you need macros if you want to use something as a predicate.

But I want to suggest that you can also compose your queries. This should give you the idea:

```
def my_predicate(query, value) do
  from r in query, where: r.some_column == ^value
end
```

And use it like:

```
query = from r in MySchema, where: r.another_column == ^another_value

query |> my_predicate(some_value)
```

Basically, build your query bit by bit, using composable functions.

PS. I always use the "query" form for Ecto queries. You can also use "piped" form and compose your query by piping query into your function.

Comment: tell me what I need, without you I don't know.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. You need a more concrete example?